# Is there way in Stream to get the SUM as intermediate operation

Tags: java, java-8, mapreduce, java-stream

As `Sum, Collect & reduce` are terminal operations.
Is there a way to compare the result of sum in a stream to return a boolean from the stream.

I wrote below code snippet to find the **Perfect Number.** 
And all it is missing is one last line to compare if the **SUM = Given Number**

```
    private static boolean isPerfectNumber(int number) {
            return IntStream.range(1, number / 2 + 1)
                            .filter(e -> number % e == 0)
                            .reduce(Integer::sum)
                            .equals(number); // This Line won't give correct result because I'm comaring an OptionalInt to a Integer instead of optional value.
    }
```

Is there a way to achieve this in this one stream or I have to compare the result separately

Comment: Why are you using `reduce(Integer::sum)` when `IntStream` has built-in method [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Use the `IntStream#sum` which uses the overloaded `reduce` API in itself:

```
return IntStream.range(1, number / 2 + 1)
                .filter(e -> number % e == 0)
                .sum() == number; // same as reduce(0, Integer::sum)
```

#### Perform an `orElse` and then comparer the integer values -

```
.reduce(Integer::sum).orElse(0) == number;
```

#### Perform `equals` amongst `OptionalInt` as

```
.reduce(Integer::sum)
.equals(OptionalInt.of(number))
```

Comment: .equals(OptionalInt.of(number)) . Seems this is what I was missing...

Comment: @ThrowableException `noneMatch`, `anyMatch` are a comparison of elements of a `Stream`, while after the `reduce` operation you are left with a single element of type `OptionalInt` which can be compared using its own APIs.

Comment: Why not use built-in method [`sum()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#sum--), which is equivalent to `reduce(0, Integer::sum)`, according to the javadoc?

Comment: @Andreas I did mention of it in the first solution in the answer. `reduce` was closer to OP's approach for better understanding anyway.

Comment: @ThrowableException to answer the title of the question, the `sum` evaluation is only a terminal operation and not an intermediate operation of the stream.

Comment: Why not keep the recommended solution (“just use `sum()`”) *and* a solution “closer to OP's approach for better understanding”?

Comment: @Holger What I had thought when I wrote the answer was, "I would let the OP decide why they should move to make use of `sum`, I would just *highlight* that while using `reduce` there is already a specific case provided within JDK as well." But I feel like, the message is not conveyed by me properly either, for various people mentioning that here. I have rephrased the answer making changes based on your and Andreas' comments. Thank you for the feedback. :)